# Nifi Processor to run multiple instance

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a use case where we are using NiFi to extract data from multiple sources. The database information for `DbcpConnectionPool` and `ExecuteSQL` processor are updated by NiFi rest api in the processor when user select the table from the custom UI. Now the issue is suppose we have triggered Oracle extraction for a particular database and at the same time some other user logs in and trigger Oracle process for some other database. Now the rest call are sent using processors ID. Since there is only one flow for oracle the second call will stop the first flow.

Is there anyway to fix this? Like dynamically create the dbcpConnection processor or processGroup for each request.

Attaching the current flow.

[image: Exiting Flow To Fetch Data From Oracle Using NiFi]

The `ListenHttp` calls contains the table Name to be fetched. Before the `ListenHttp` call is made a rest call is made to update the dbcpConnectionPool with URL and details and also update the `ExecuteSql` Processor with necessary processor. Now if in between one request being served another request comes up how to handle that.

Comment: do you have only one `ExcecuteSQL` processor to get information from dynamically connected database?

Comment: 2 ExecuteSQL processor. The MyProcessor in the picture above is a custom ExecuteSQL but with batch and fetch size property. One processor to fetch DDLs of table and second to fetch the data.

Comment: in the nifi 1.7.x it's possible to switch database connections dynamically. or if you can't switch to 1.7 you can use script to connect to db, execute query on it, and produce the json result.

Comment: But what if the previous fetch is not completed and i switched connection. How will it affect the existing flow?

Comment: @daggett any thoughts on same?

Comment: in nifi 1.7 it should work. in script - it's possible to create connection to db without connection pool service - just pure jdbc connection - so it will not affect any parallel running flowfile/process.